# installing ubuntu with windows 8, which was not pre installed

Tags: installation

My Pc came pre installed with windows 7. Since then I have upgraded to Win 8 64bit. Can I use the ubuntu windows installer to dual boot both operating systems?

Comment: Its better to install ubuntu on the hard-disk other than using windows installer.

Comment: yes you can , but it would be comparably slow ,So go with Aviash suggestion..

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded Ubuntu 13.10 and installed it using "Universal USB Installer" (From: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) on my other computer which was upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 8 (Both 64-Bit).

I had used WUBI.exe before, but found that installing it from USB (Or DVD if you have them available) worked much more efficiently. I have not run into any problems dual-booting using this method.